# Create the "skeleton" of a custom PSObject from scratch

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PSCustomObject that will later on be converted to JSON as the body of an API request.

This body basically has a structure to add / remove different information to a security management tool policy (filehash / filenames / certificates / IPs / file extensions / folders exceptions, on which technology etc.)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/FaKYpgw3) is an example of a final JSON with all the possibilities.
As a proof of concept, I'm focusing on the following part which is adding a filename & a filehash to the exception policy

```
{
"add": {
    "applications": [
        {
            "processfile": {
                "sha2": "6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea",
                "name": "myfilename"
            }
        }
    ]
...
```

My goal is not to import this specific JSON as a custom Object, (I know this can be done through convertfrom-Json). It's to create some empty object, but with the correct structure matching the JSON format. This way, I would just have to populate and access information in my object like this :

```
PS C:\PSSymantecCloud> $obj.add.applications

processfile
-----------
@{sha2=6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea; name=myfilename}

PS C:\PSSymantecCloud> $obj.add.applications.processfile

sha2                                                             name
----                                                             ----
6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea myfilename
```

I've been trying to play around with **Format-Custom** CmdLet but without success.
Any suggestions on how to create such a custom PSObject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fond of [PowerShell classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2) so here is one way to do it with them. You can add new `processfile` with the `AddProcessFile` method that takes 2 arguments as in your Json:

```
class addjson {
    [object] $add

    addjson() {
        $this.add = [pscustomobject]@{
            applications = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        }
    }

    [void] AddProcessFile([string] $sha2, [string] $name) {
        $this.add.applications.Add([pscustomobject]@{
            processfile = [pscustomobject]@{
                sha2 = $sha2
                name = $name
            }
        })
    }
}

$add = [addjson]::new()
$add.AddProcessFile('6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea', 'myFile')
$add.AddProcessFile('6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea', 'myFile2')
$add | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

Resulting Json would be:

```json
{
  "add": {
    "applications": [
      {
        "processfile": {
          "sha2": "6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea",
          "name": "myFile"
        }
      },
      {
        "processfile": {
          "sha2": "6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea",
          "name": "myFile2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an psObject shell, assign empty strings ““, or $false to the properties

```
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Name = ““  
      SecondProperty= ““
      yetAnotherProoerty= ““

  }
```

Later u can assign your results like this:

```
$Object.name= $myResult
```

Or even add new member aka properties to the object like this:

```
Object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Status -NotePropertyValue Done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just take your sample text and convert it with convertto-json. e.g.

```
$HereString = @"
{
    "add": {
        "applications": [
            {
                "processfile": {
                    "sha2": "6ddc5c11925ab348eb0d390ec5179c1d655eb4bf70779f7a4e28b7db485d20ea",
                    "name": "myfilename"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
"@ 

$PSObject = $HereString | ConvertFrom-Json

$PSObject | get-member
```